# Why is Ansible's ec2.py dynamic inventory script so slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to work with dynamic inventory in Ansible, i.e. a dynamic list of host IPs to connect to. [Ansible's site](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-aws-ec2) provides a script called `ec2.py` which automatically fetches this inventory and allows usage like so:

```
ansible-playbook -i ec2.py ...
```

However, the script is super slow, taking **about a full minute** to execute. Ansible's site claims the AWS API is slow, but I don't buy it. How can fetching 3-6 IPs be THIS slow!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The script is slow because it checks for instance in every existing AWS region. Searching only the regions you know have instances will be almost instant.**

There are 2 ways to set your AWS region for `ec2.py`

1. Specify `regions = ...` in `/etc/ansible/ec2.ini`. This method actually works.
2. Specify the `export AWS_REGION=...` environment variable. **This method is currently [broken](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/64343#issuecomment-549033310), and Ansible has made no attempt at fixing it.** One quick fix is to change the default region from 'all' to 'auto' (which will read the env variable if there is no ini file):

   ```
   sed -i "s|'regions': 'all'|'regions': 'auto'|" ec2.py
   ```